# React Component Loads Halfway Down The Page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, components

i'm building my portfolio in react and im running into an issue. On my home page, i scroll down to reach the project section, and when i click on a link to view the project, the new component loads, but it seems to load at the same position i was on my component before (halfway down the page). Any way to fix this?

Code for my project component:

```
<Project
        thumbnail={ProjectBg}
        title={this.state.MyHumberTitle}
        description={this.state.MyHumberDesc}
        type={this.state.MyHumberType}
        path={this.state.MyHumberPath}
      />
```

[image: Home Page Component]
[image: Project Component Being Loaded]

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I updated with code and images as example

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely the expected, though idiosyncratic behavior. Your web page loads, you set a scroll position, and when you programmatically change what shows up on the screen, nothing tells the browser to update the scroll position programmatically as well.

When I'm using a router, I usually include a `<ScrollToTop>` component which listens for route changes, as described here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/scroll-restoration.md.

It seems like you aren't using a router, so you'll need to tie your programmatic scroll update to some changes in state. Whenever the state changes in a way that will present a new page of information, you need to scroll back to the top.

No matter what, here's how you're going to reset the scroll:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0)
```

And you'll probably be tying that into a `componentDidUpdate` function or a `useEffect` call with the appropriate pieces of state as change conditions (the second, array arg).

Answer (score 0):

Solution to anyone having this issue, In the new component you want to load, add:

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }
```